# Why isn't my animation visible?

Tags: java, swing, animation

So this is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Frame {

Draw d = new Draw();

JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Animation 2");
JButton bMoveRight = new JButton(">>>>");
JButton bMoveLeft = new JButton("<<<<");

public Frame() {

    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setSize(800, 600);
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setResizable(false);
    f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    bMoveRight.setBounds(50, 450, 120, 50);
    bMoveLeft.setBounds(600, 450, 120, 50);

    f1.add(bMoveRight);
    f1.add(bMoveLeft);

    f1.add(d);

    bMoveRight.addActionListener(new ButtonMoveRight());
    bMoveLeft.addActionListener(new ButtonMoveLeft());

    }

    private class ButtonMoveRight implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            d.animateRight();
        }
    }

    private class ButtonMoveLeft implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            d.animateLeft();
        }
    }

}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Draw extends JComponent{

int x = 50;

public void paint(Graphics g){  
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, 150, 200, 100);
}

public void animateLeft(){
    try{
        while(x != 50){
            x--;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void animateRight(){
    try{
        while(x != 550){
            x++;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Everything works as it should. Except one thing. My animation happens but the problem is it doesn't show. I made another program where there is only animation and it starts right away,but in this one I made buttons to start the animations. What happens is I click the button and nothing happens for 5 seconds (that's the time it needs to get to the other side) and after 5 seconds it appears on the other side of the window. Why won't my animation show?

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

The Thread.sleep() inside your "ActionListener" callbacks is strongly discouraged. The issue is the following: your code is invoked in the same thread which is main thread for GUI application - it is used to draw your interface.

What you need to do instead of sleep() invocation - you can fire some events with delay and process right way. You have to use something like timer - probably this one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html